# Parameter is not valid. retrieving image in sql in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve image in sql. i tried every solution. nothing works.

```
SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("prodName", lvItem));     

SqlDataReader reader;
connection.Open();
reader = command2.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    byte[] image = (byte[])reader["productImage"]; // converting image to byte
    if (image == null)
    {
        pbPicture.Image = null;
    }
    else
    {
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(image);
        pbPicture.Image = `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memory);  //Parameter is not valid
    }

}
```

I tried every solution. nothing works. please help! i'm still learning

Comment: string query2 = "Select productImage from product where productName = @prodName";

Comment: SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
            command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("prodName", lvItem)); this is my query..

Comment: Does it comes inside while loop ?

Comment: What datatype is pbPicture.Image?

Comment: My guess is that you image is raw rgb(a) data. That's why you get the exception. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x%28v=vs.100%29 comments at the bottom of the page..

Comment: @vaughnellisramos What is the data type of picture column in database? And did you debug if the 'image' property is filled with bytes after the line: byte[] image = (byte[])reader["productImage"]; ?

Comment: the data type of picture column is image. and yes i debug the image property after the line: byte[] image = (byte[])reader["productImage"];

Comment: @MilenPavlov so what should i do? i'm still learning.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen pbPicture is a picture box.. the data type of picture column is image. thanks for responding

Comment: Also - just to make sure, but that ` character you have in front of System.Drawing.Image .... is that intentionally?

Comment: typo error. it's just  pbPicture.Image = Image.FromStream(memory);

Answer (score 0):

I think Your parameter should be like this `@prodName` and Specify some Size;

```
command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("prodName", lvItem));
```

to

```
SqlParameter para=new SqlParameter("@prodName", SqlDbType.Varchar,50);
para.Value=lvItem;
```

Comment: nope it didn't work.. please help me. i've been looking for a solution for 2 days. i tried every solution in youtube and in stackoverflow. nothing works.

Comment: SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
            SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter("@prodName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            para.Value = lvItem;
reader = command2.ExecuteReader(); // must declare scalar variable.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem might be from your insert statement. I had a similar issue, it will insert but will never retrieve, telling me Parameter not Valid.

Try to Use Parameterized Queries while Inserting

Like this

```
scom.CommandText = "insert into Quest ( [TopicT_Id], [Quest], [Image1] ) values (  '" + Guid.NewGuid() + "', '" + quest + "', @image)";
scom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", imagebyte);
```

Instead of

```
scom.CommandText = "insert into Quest ( [TopicT_Id], [Quest], [Image1] ) values (  '" + Guid.NewGuid() + "', '" + quest + "','"+imagebyte+"')";
```

I realised that while inserting the image without using parameters, the Image Values which are forced between ' ' all turns to varchar or other string formats.